# Magneto 2 : How to change shopping bag icon

Tags: cart, magento2.3, shopping-cart, icon

I want to change the shopping cart icon. I want to add a new image, how to do that. I am using Magento 2.3

> https://prnt.sc/osf50f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before** selector to change the icon in your custom stylesheet

> example path: app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme_name}/web/css/custom.css

```
.minicart-wrapper .showcart::before {
    content: "" !important;
    background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/222653/shopping-cart.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 27px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 37px !important;
}
```

Then **Clear Cache** and try

Comment: Can u tell me In which file i can add this?

Comment: please copy and  paste the above code in your custom style sheet (ex: style.css ..)

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: can i add image url in content itself?

Comment: please add url here   background: url('image-url-paste-here');

Comment: This code is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97406/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-nafisa).

Comment: Please Check updated answer

Comment: @ShafeelSha My image under web/image folder,  how to include the image?

Comment: background: url('../web/image/image.png') no-repeat; try this way to access image